# How to display list of files under a particular directory in Drupal?

Tags: 7, files

I've created a custom module to export node data of different content types into Excel (using PHPExcel hooks).

That will be stored into particular directory called "***Reports***" under ***site/all/files*** directory.

Now I would like to display the list of files exists under "***Reports***" directory, in a page/view in a table format.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a module called [Filebrowser](https://www.drupal.org/project/filebrowser) for this.

> Allows site administrators to expose a particular file system folder and all of its subfolders with a fancy FTP-like interface to site visitors. File metainformation (via descript.ion and files.bss) is supported. The module also allows these metafiles to store special content, which can be parsed with a callback. If no callback is specified in the file, only the description will be fetched.

This is the exact module what I was looking for. Using this module I could display all my exported files. Here is the screen-shot.

[image]

Additionally we can ***Delete*** the files and also download the selected items as an ***ZIP archive*** from here itself.

Hope this post helps someone.