# List files in a directory as a table

Tags: views, theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms, database

I created a folder inside of my Drupal directory where my client can directly FTP into and upload or remove PDFs.

What I'm trying to do is create a page called "Documents" which then displays all PDFs in that directory as a table. So when a new PDF is either uploaded or deleted a new row is either added or deleted in the table.

I found this thread here: [Can you create a view to display all files within a certain directory?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10279/can-you-create-a-view-to-display-all-files-within-a-certain-directory?rq=1) - And was looking into [Filebrowser](https://www.drupal.org/project/filebrowser).

The problem is I want to be able to control the front end look of the table. Because the function of the table would be for users to be able to download and view the PDFs that the client uploaded in the directory.

Would this approach here by my best solution, I'm trying to stay away from using any outside modules. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559308/how-can-i-list-files-in-a-directory-using-php

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Filebrowser](https://www.drupal.org/project/filebrowser) module is what you looking for :

```
This module provides an interface for administrators to expose directories on the file system to users through a file listing as in a FTP application.

You will create one node (node type dir_listing) for each each Directory Listing (DL). Node settings are used to control access and other features of the DL. These settings can vary per node and per user.

This module offers the following features:

Private downloads so that files (such as PHP files) can be downloaded.
File blacklists so that specific files can be removed from directory listings.
Node-based. All features available to nodes, such as path aliasing and access control can be applied to directory listings.
Settings to limit exploration of subdirectories
```

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to using the Filebrowser approach just because of the lack of control I have for the end user.

Comment: I created a new view and I'm showing "Files" from what I'm reading I can create a filter that will show only the files in that specified folder. Under filter criteria I selected  "URI" but not too sure how I would select the appropriate folder. I currently have the folder in sites/default/files/pdf-uploads

Comment: @hisusu32 . cool. its another solution. but keep in mind , what you've done is just for fiels that are uploaded by Drupal ( registered in Drupal file table) not supported PDFs uploaded by FTP!

Comment: Ahh you're right! I think this is the problem I'm currently running into. Well, back to the drawing board. If I weren't to use Filebrowser how else would you approach this?